# Server 2008 locks me out when not using the machine for 10 minutes after installing SP2

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have recently installed Service Pack 2 on my Windows Server 2008 machine (which I use actively for development, and i'm always logged on to).

Now, after this installation, when I don't use the machine for some time (let's say, 10 minutes), it locks itself so I have to press Ctrl+Alt+Del and log back in.

I have already checked the Screen Saver settings, and it's "None", as it always has been. I also looked into power settings and everything looks right (20 mins to turn off monitor, and i haven't found any settings regarding locking me in there).

Do you have any idea what I can do so that it won't lock me out after not using the machine for a while?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here:

https://superuser.com/questions/51416/server-2008-locks-me-out-when-not-using-the-machine-for-10-minutes-after-installi/51425#51425

Answer (score 1):

Try running rsop.msc (Resultant Set of Policy) on the machine in question and browse to Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings and check to see if there is a domain policy overriding the local settings regarding screen savers / idle time / etc.

thanks,
mark